# How to know if i can access my intranet computer from outside the network?

Tags: networking, debug

Trying to debug some remote processes, and i'm inside an intranet.

I use a debugger that has a server which listens for connections, and in the debugged code, i make a call via the debugger API, to my server, something like this `debugger.connect(host='localhost')`

When the debugged code is also inside the intranet (a virtual machine on my workstation, to be specific), i can easily provide the IP of my local server via the `host` parameter.

Would it be possible to refer to my local server from outside the intranet, so that i can debug as i usually do?

**[EDIT]**
I know that `localhost` refers to the local machine on which the word `localhost` is interpreted. I'm asking : how to refer to my computer from outside my intranet, or how to know if that's doable at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your intranet is connected to the Internet? If so, it's probably behind a NAT router, which would mean that the IP allocation inside the network is different from outside. This is a commons network security measure. More info on [HowStuffWorks](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/nat.htm):

> Network Address Translation allows a single device, such as a router, to act as an agent between the Internet (or "public network") and a local (or "private") network. This means that only a single, unique IP address is required to represent an entire group of computers.

This essentially means that you need to use a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) to access the intranet. Your organization probably has one set up, so I would ask them. If not, try [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/), which should work for you.